# Eclipse Neon 4.6 - find box doesn't show up

Tags: eclipse

After pressing ctrl-F, I can't see 'Find' window. Yesterday I had it.
It's quite important feature - how can I get it back?

Eclipse Neon 4.6, Ubuntu 14.

Comment: What part is active? You won't get a find dialog if Package or Project Explorer is active for example.

Comment: In Project Explorer after pressing Ctrl-F, little window shows up in at the bottom - lokks ok. In code editor part after pressing Ctrl-F, only cursor disapears.